# How to control version of postgresql by homebrew

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

Today I wanted to use postgresql 10.6 for `this` project and postgresql 11.2 for `that` project.

I could successfully did 11.2 -> 10.6 as follows. It worked.

```
that$ cd ../this
this$ brew services stop postgresql
this$ brew unlink postgresql
this$ brew link postgresql@10 --force
this$ brew services start postgresql@10
```

But when I came back to that project and tried to do 10.6 -> 11.2 it did not work.

```
this$ cd ../that
that$ brew services stop postgresql@10
that$ brew unlink postgresql@10
that$ brew link postgresql
that$ brew services start postgresql
```

Then I got following error message, when I did `psql`. I searched StackOverflow and found it's a quite famous error. I tried many different answers but nothing worked (I didn't want to reinstall postgresql by the way).

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Have you tried above commands for a similar reason I have, and experienced the same error? If so, then have you found a solution?

Comment: Not right answer, so just a comment - use docker. Then 10 -> 11 and back is just a question of start\stop a container.

Comment: I think it was `initdb <directory>` I did something like `initdb /usr/local/var/postgresql/` after I moved to 11. Looks like the error happened because there's no database

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that postgresql is not running, but it's hard to say why that would be the case with the provided information.

The brew install command outputs a few lines as it finishes. One of those lines should contain instructions for directly running the service, which will help narrow down the issue.

```
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
```

For me, running the command gave me the error

```
postgres: could not access directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14": No such file or directory
```

And checking for that directory, it was not there, but there was another directory `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres`.

To resolve the issue, I used `pg_upgrade` to migrate the data from the data directory that existed to the new one referenced in the run command.